# Continue a music playlist as an Alarm

Tags: automation, music-player, alarm

Back when Google Play was still alive, I found an Automate script that would turn on the app at a specific time, continuing whatever playlist it had last been going through. It made for a really handy alarm, since I wouldn't reflexively turn off music the way I would an alarm, especially as it changed every day. And I really appreciated it continuing the playlist since I could curate the play order and manually switch to another playlist at the end.

Ever since Google nixed Play in favor of Youtube Music, I haven't found a way to replicate that - the only way I can get YT Music to play a playlist in order with an alarm is if it starts over every morning, which really doesn't help you get through a 50 song playlist over time.

Is there a way to use a music service as an alarm like that? To continue the set playlist in order where it left off the morning before? I'll entertain any music app and automation combination, but am really hoping there's just some setting I missed in the default Clock/YouTube Music combo.